# how to use clearInteval let timer clear it self in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I am new to react, I am trying to write a react component, component has several features.

1. user can input a random number, then number will be displayed in the
   page too.
2. implement a button with text value 'start', once click the button,
   the number value displayed will reduce one every 1second and the
   text value will become 'stop'.
3. continue click button, minus one will stop and text value of button
   will become back to 'start'.
4. when number subtracted down to 0 will automatically stop itself.

I have implemented first three features. but I am not sure how do I start the last one. should I set another `clearInteval`? based on `if statement` when timer counts down 0?

code is here:

```js
    var myTimer;

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          details: [{ id: 1, number: "" }],
          type: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
      changeNumber = (e, target) => {
        this.setState({
          details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
            if (detail.id === target.id) {
              detail.number = e.target.value;
            }
            return detail;
          })
        });
      };

      handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          type: !prevState.type
        }));
        if (this.state.type === false) {
          myTimer = setInterval(
            () =>
              this.setState({
                details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
                  if (detail.id) {
                    detail.number = parseInt(detail.number) - 1;
                  }
                  return detail;
                })
              }),
            1000
          );
        }
        if (this.state.type === true) {
          clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.details.map(detail => {
              return (
                <div key={detail.id}>
                  Number:{detail.number}
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    onChange={e => this.changeNumber(e, detail)}
                    value={detail.number}
                  />
                  <input
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
                    value={this.state.type ? "stop" : "start"}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Challenge accepted

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
if (detail.number === 0) {
 clearInterval(myTimer);
}
```

in

```
handleClick = () => {

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        type: !prevState.type
    }));

    if (this.state.type === false) {
        myTimer = setInterval(
            () =>
                this.setState({
                    details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
                        if (detail.id) {
                            detail.number = parseInt(detail.number) - 1;
                            if (detail.number === 0) {
                                clearInterval(myTimer);
                            }
                        }
                        return detail;
                    })
                }),
            1000
        );
    }
    if (this.state.type === true) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
};
```

---

Here You have this solution on Hooks :)

```
const Test2 = () => {

    const [on, setOn] = useState(false)

    const initialDetails = [{ id: 1, number: "" }]
    const [details, setDetails] = useState(initialDetails)

    const changeNumber = (e, target) => {
        setDetails({ details: details.map(detail => { if (detail.id === target.id) { detail.number = e.target.value; } return detail; }) });
        if (this.state.details.number === 0) { setOn(false) }
    };


    const handleClick = () => {
        if (on === false) {myTimer = setInterval(() =>
                    setDetails({details: details.map(detail => {if (detail.id) {detail.number = parseInt(detail.number) - 1; if (detail.number === 0) {clearInterval(myTimer);} }
                            return detail;})}),1000);}
        if (on === true) { clearInterval(myTimer); }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {details.map(detail => {
                return (
                    <div key={detail.id}>
                        Number:{detail.number}
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            onChange={e => changeNumber(e, detail)}
                            value={detail.number}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => handleClick()}
                            value={on ? "stop" : "start"}
                        />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```